# Flask - Use HTML tags on TextAreaField

Tags: python, html, flask

I have this simple Post Form class

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
  content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

Is there a way so that when the user inputs

```
<a href="example.com">example</a>
```

on the TextAreaField the site outputs it as an HTML link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to be more specific about where and when the link is shown, but if the value of the TextAreaField is being displayed through Jinja, you can use the [`|safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#safe) template filter, which will prevent auto escaping characters.

E.g. In your html:

```
{{ content|safe }}
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple to solve this... Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{url_for('PostForm')}}" method = 'POST'>
   <div>
     <label for="link">Name:</label>
     <input type ='text' name='link' placeholder="Enter Link here" required>
     <input type='submit' value='Create'>
   </div>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, it calls below function using url_for() in python

```
@app.route('/link', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def PostForm():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        link = request.form['link']
        print(link)
        return render_template('new.html', link=link)
```

In new.html write the below code

```
<body>
<a href='{{link}}'>link</a>
</body>
```

When user enters link and click on Create button. It redirects to new.html and provides a link.